# Validating google recaptcha with requestify?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to validate recaptcha using requestify. This is what the docs says about the api:

```
API Request

URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

METHOD: POST

POST      Parameter Description
secret    Required.  The shared key between your site and ReCAPTCHA.
response  Required.  The user response token provided by the reCAPTCHA to the user and provided to your site on.
remoteip  Optional.  The user's IP address.
```

This is my request

```
    requestify.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', {
            secret: '**********',
            response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response'],
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.body);
         })
```

The response i get is

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "missing-input-response",
    "missing-input-secret"
  ]
}
```

I think I may be posting the parameters in the wrong way or maybe I misuderstand the api docs.

Comment: I hope your secret is not the real private Key. Which should remain "private"

Comment: It is just a dev-secret, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use "request" but it should work the same way.

```
var request = require('request');

var data = {
  remoteip:  req.connection.remoteAddress, // @IP of the user
  response:  req.body["g-recaptcha-response"], 
  secret: RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY
};

request.post({
  'url': RECAPTCHA_URL, 
  form: data, 
  'proxy': HTTP_PROXY // (optional) I'm behind a proxy
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var b = JSON.parse(body);
    if ( b.success === true ) {
      // ... your code here
    } else // ... 
  } else // .... 

});
```